# How to visualize Earth Engine image with a minimum scale parameter?

Tags: qgis, python, google-earth-engine, pyqgis-3

I am trying to visualize outputs of Earth Engine with QGIS plugin. The problem arises when I want to analyze an output of a KMeans model. When I zoom in, the result changes and becomes vague to interpret. I guess it is due to dynamic scale parameter. Can I set a scale, at least a minimum one, for Earth Engine, such as scale > 10, when I want to visualize the result?

It is necessary since I want to analyze and draw polygons accordingly at a high zoom level.

Here is the visualization differences:

[Zoom Level 1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSGoc.jpg

[Zoom Level 2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivWYj.jpg

[Zoom Level 3] https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO6IU.jpg

Here is my pyqgis code:

```
import ee
from ee_plugin import Map

sentinelCollect = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")

tRegion = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
       [[[35.13622309678544, 36.64880746395306],
          [35.139141340193646, 36.64984039840571],
          [35.146436948714154, 36.64718917212176],
          [35.15047099107255, 36.64584630840383],
          [35.150642652449505, 36.6448477535381],
          [35.15221979135026, 36.64457228784864],
          [35.152369995055096, 36.644391512954535],
          [35.152638215956586, 36.64415047910238],
          [35.15324975961198, 36.64384057732704],
          [35.153646726546185, 36.64368562597179],
          [35.15453721993913, 36.64371145121932],
          [35.15497710221757, 36.643616758602754],
          [35.155395526823895, 36.64368562597179],
          [35.1556852053975, 36.64359093332347],
          [35.155931968626874, 36.64343598146603],
          [35.15683319085588, 36.643668409135316],
          [35.157380361494916, 36.643616758602754],
          [35.15794898980607, 36.643504848996706],
          [35.158378143248456, 36.64341876457373],
          [35.15875365251054, 36.643504848996706],
          [35.15946175569047, 36.64360815017727],
          [35.16006257050981, 36.643547891172126],
          [35.1603307914113, 36.64346180679724],
          [35.16050245278825, 36.643341288510804],
          [35.16047026628007, 36.6431174683357],
          [35.16119982713212, 36.643091642889026],
          [35.16153242104997, 36.64300555800426],
          [35.16230822777982, 36.64225661544736],
          [35.16327382302518, 36.6418817586935],
          [35.16467930054898, 36.64157184779045],
          [35.16573072648282, 36.64176123793491],
          [35.166127693417025, 36.64161489104599],
          [35.166857254269075, 36.64148576120722],
          [35.167104017498446, 36.64150297853156],
          [35.1682305452847, 36.64150297853156],
          [35.16848803735013, 36.6414771525436],
          [35.168852817776155, 36.640908978617965],
          [35.169614565136385, 36.64035801808188],
          [35.170344125988436, 36.64010836279165],
          [35.1719625529156, 36.63946269880638],
          [35.172917419324904, 36.64059906380128],
          [35.17374353970149, 36.64013418923851],
          [35.173668437849074, 36.6397467916266],
          [35.17401176060298, 36.6395229610073],
          [35.173625522504835, 36.63892033687679],
          [35.17374353970149, 36.63873093974791],
          [35.175159746061354, 36.63880760552052],
          [35.175653272520094, 36.63848046425402],
          [35.175996595274, 36.63820497579423],
          [35.176597410093336, 36.638248020931],
          [35.17709093655208, 36.63811027640867],
          [35.17748790348628, 36.637852004765506],
          [35.17772393787959, 36.63779174125751],
          [35.178153091321974, 36.637585123157955],
          [35.17874317730525, 36.63745598656435],
          [35.1794727381573, 36.63728380410283],
          [35.18006282414058, 36.637034138850126],
          [35.18055635059932, 36.636715599249655],
          [35.180642181287794, 36.636483150601904],
          [35.1809318598614, 36.63639705833217],
          [35.18118935192683, 36.636689771656734],
          [35.18152194584468, 36.63681030034952],
          [35.18203692997554, 36.636836127902],
          [35.182401710401564, 36.636732817640095],
          [35.18257337177852, 36.63643149525162],
          [35.1829488810406, 36.63636262139736],
          [35.18329220379451, 36.63633679368612],
          [35.183646255384474, 36.63623348275466],
          [35.18469768131831, 36.63627789462062],
          [35.188413784332965, 36.63445466032189],
          [35.192941353150104, 36.63324071847539],
          [35.1987413064935, 36.63123960733605],
          [35.20157371921323, 36.62975870612329],
          [35.203934063146335, 36.628381098050795],
          [35.20582233829282, 36.62827777645265],
          [35.20685230655454, 36.627313434857115],
          [35.2082685129144, 36.62648684674292],
          [35.21058594150327, 36.62552436285994],
          [35.212688793370944, 36.62483552405791],
          [35.215392460057956, 36.62442221782178],
          [35.21770988864682, 36.62373336917005],
          [35.22024189395688, 36.62242453977209],
          [35.22208725375913, 36.622183437195936],
          [35.22298847598813, 36.622631198522875],
          [35.22410427493833, 36.62672981595032],
          [35.22599255008481, 36.626523168188065],
          [35.23174320621274, 36.62018570112693],
          [35.243158687780124, 36.6189457009762],
          [35.250625957677585, 36.610747420433825],
          [35.2667070891996, 36.599584248890665],
          [35.287364070590684, 36.58979782713126],
          [35.275405607781636, 36.60344073464478],
          [35.25332188734717, 36.621350581472626],
          [35.22648729423952, 36.64118314740452],
          [35.21281068496285, 36.648611731486774],
          [35.208287361337625, 36.64845526783897],
          [35.16255644365572, 36.6680536842811]]]);

#tRegion = ee.FeatureCollection(tRegion)

#Map.centerObject(tRegion)

# Import Image
img = ee.Image(sentinelCollect
  .filterBounds(tRegion)
  .filterDate('2019-12-20', '2019-12-30')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
  .first()
  .select(["B2","B3","B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8"])
).clip(tRegion)

ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI')
img2 = img.addBands(ndvi)
img3 = img2.toUint16()

glcm = img3.glcmTexture(size = 3).select(["B8_ent", "B8_contrast",
                                          "B8_asm","B5_ent", "B5_contrast",
                                          "B5_asm","NDVI_ent", "NDVI_contrast", "NDVI_asm"])

img4 = img3.addBands(glcm).toUint16().clip(tRegion)

v_seed = 1222

# Get training data
training = img4.sample(region = tRegion,
                       scale = 10,
                       numPixels = 3000)

clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(50).train(training)
result = img4.cluster(clusterer)

# Visualize layers
Map.addLayer(result.randomVisualizer(), {}, 'clusters')
```

Similar problem with EE API, as well: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b9ffa6297d8f985c324078ad8f0c9413